# Chilkat "Cannot get ActiveX Interface"

Tags: autoit, chilkat

When I use this snippets:

```
Local $oTask = $oHttp.DownloadBdAsync("https://.............pl/..........", $oBinData)
ConsoleWrite($oHttp.LastErrorText)
```

I get this error:

> ```
> ChilkatLog:   
> ActiveXError:
> DllDate: Sep 28 2020
> ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.84
> UnlockPrefix: ************
> Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
> Language: ActiveX
> VerboseLogging: 0
> Cannot get ActiveX Interface   
> --ActiveXError
> --ChilkatLog
> ```

**Why I get this error ?**

btw.

```
Local $iSuccess = $oHttp.DownloadBd("https://.............pl/..........", $oBinData)
ConsoleWrite($oHttp.LastErrorText)
```

Works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is correct, but in other languages the "Set" keyword would be needed if an object is returned instead of a primitive value.  Given that a Chilkat async method returns a Chilkat Task object (https://chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatTaskRef.html) perhaps this is the solution:

```html
 Local $oTask
 Set $oTask = $oHttp.DownloadBdAsync("https://.............pl/..........", $oBinData)
```

This is just a guess...

Comment: `Autoit` doesn't use `set`. The syntax used in the question is fine.

Comment: Try re-registering the Chilkat ActiveX DLL.  It may be that somehow registration entries in the Windows registry were deleted by something unrelated to Chilkat.

Comment: This is a good tip, as I do not have registered object, I use technique which do not require registering. So now I wonder if the main object is accesible for me in my DEVEnvironment on runtime, why all the **Async methods require separate way of accessing the same object ?

Comment: It's because Chilkat is returning a new instance of the Task object.  To create the ActiveX object instance (from within the C++ implementation) requires that the ActiveX DLL be registered.

Comment: Just checked with registered dll.
Works fine......   
Here [link](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatTaskRef.html) I can see that I can use  this kind of code  
 `(VBScript)
set obj = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Task")`  
to create such obejct.

Comment: So I was curious how I can use them, but here `https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/` I was not able to find any example how to create this object and use them. So I assume that Task object is always created internally by the DLL ?
I found also that I can create the Task object by my self with my technique (without dll registering) so I ask is there a way to create this task object by my self and flag them to DLL that this my instance will be used for next tiem when ActiveX object should to create new instance ?